# Typescript: Invalid Object.assign type?

Tags: typescript

Why is `Object.assign({}, null)` typed as `{} & null` in Typescript 2.6.2 instead of just `{}`?

Comment: How are you determining how `Object.assign({}, null)` is typed?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the TypeScript definition for Object.assign](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L275):

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
```

`assign` can be parameterized, so you could have `Object.assign<SourceType, TargetType>(sourceInstance, targetInstance)`. In this case the source and target would be a intersection type of `SourceType & TargetType` as specified in the type definition above.

The reason for this is that they can have different properties.

```
const sourceInstance = { a: 'b' };
const targetInstance = { c: 'd' };
Object.assign(sourceInstance, targetInstance); // { a: 'b', c: 'd' }
```

As you can see the result is the intersection of the two types. Thus, if you pass in an empty object `{}` and `null` you get the intersection type of `{} & null`.

`null` is allowed in `Object.assign` and is essentially ignored: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: The same appears true with any non-object primitive type. I'm surprised TS is just returning a union here. Seems like there needs to be a language-level construct for filtering out non-object types.

Comment: @LeeBenson `Object.assign` allows non-object types (or takes the "everything is an object" tack). `Object.assign(2, null)` works for example.

Comment: yup, I understand. But IMO, TS isn't doing the right thing. `Object.assign(2, null)` is typed as `2 & null`, when it'll only _ever_ return a Number. Union feels wrong here.

Comment: @LeeBenson this is just based on TS creating a union type for the arguments to `Object.assign`. I'm not sure that TypeScript has the capability to create conditional types. Regardless, `null` as a intersectional type doesn't have any effect since `null` has no properties.

Comment: The word "union" has a specific meaning which is different from (and dual to) the word "intersection".  "`T & U`"  is not a union; it's an interesection.

Comment: @jcalz good point; sorry I thought I had corrected this but I didn't